# Почему в окне Tkinter такое плохое качество отображения текста?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, tkinter, шрифты

Делаю приложение с tkinter'ом. Но очень не нравиться качество отображения текста (фото). Можно ли это как-то улучшить? Сделать более гладким?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В пример привел строчку кода из PyCharm. Текст более гладкий, на него приятнее смотреть (дело не в шрифте).

Comment: Возможно поможет поставить тему. К примеру вот так у меня выглядит тема azure (ссылки к сожалению не дам так что гугл наше все). Вот скрин https://www.screencast.com/t/0J66uFC4F

Comment: а другие шрифты пробовали ?

Comment: @Интик да, тот же самый Consolas (как в PyCharm), выглядит также размыто

Comment: а вон тот последний ответ не поможет ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41315873/attempting-to-resolve-blurred-tkinter-text-scaling-on-windows-10-high-dpi-disp

Comment: @Интик действительно помогло, спасибо